# Microsoft word 2003 when I am making deletions or changes they show up on the document in a balloon

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

I am writing a novel in microsoft word 2003, and I am pretty far into it, but one time I hit a one of the F keys (I don't know which one) by accident.

Now everytime I go on word I have these stupid balloons with writing in them and all my deletions and everything are highlighted shown.

I looked up on google how to stop this and I did as it says, and it worked the balloon with the deletions and all the changes dissapeared, but next time I opened up the document they were back, and they always keep coming back, so when I send my document to anyone it shows them all my deletions and changes I made to the document.

Can anyone help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You must have switched on "Track Changes" accidentally. Switching it off will solve your problem.

The shortcut key that toggles Track Changes is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can turn it off from `Tools > Track Changes` menu. This is the official page of Microsoft about that issue: [Turn on or off change tracking.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP030829141033.aspx?pid=CH063555981033)

Comment: Thank but it doesn't work, there is a tick on ink anotation, formatting, comments and insertions and deletions.

I un tick these then say accept all changes, then I go to tools and click track changes, and it all goes away until I open my word document again and it is back, and anyone I send it to it comes up for them too I am quite worried about this as I feel I may have destroyed my novel, because I can't show it to anyone if this keeps coming up because it looks rubbish when all the deletions and everything is showing.